Hp chromebook school computer
How do you remove Enterprise enrollment from a computer from a school elementary school because I've tried so many times and it didn't work so I just need help doing it with its really really strong like I don't know I don't know how to take it off it's just keep popping up every time I power wash it so like can you help me please

You don’t; At least not with the previous owner assistance
